# Usage of U2Net Model in android

Tags: android, pytorch, image-segmentation, tensorflow-lite

I converted the original u2net model weight file u2net.pth to tensorflow lite by following these [instructructions](https://qiita.com/PINTO/items/ed06e03eb5c007c2e102), and it is converted successfully.

However I'm having trouble using it in android in tensrflow lite, I was not being able to add the image segmenter metadata to this model with [tflite-support script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/blob/master/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata_writers/image_segmenter.py), so I changed the model and returned only 1 output d0 (which is a combination of all i.e d1,d2,...,d7). Then metadata was added successfully and I was able to use the model, but its not giving any output and returning the same image .

So any help would be much appreciated, in letting me know where I messed up, and how can I use this use this u2net model properly in tensorflow lite with android, thanks in advance ..

Comment: Add a link for the first .tflite file to take a look. You can also use the model without adding the metadata. So maybe the solution is the first one with multiple outputs

Comment: @Farmaker here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h5sLWa7gqDSvi_2LqmMmAW0jx5uIzc7W/view?usp=sharing) to 1st .tflite models (float32 variant) which has multiple outputs, and if I don't add the metadata I get this error while running the app:
'Error occurred when initializing ImageSegmenter: Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images'

Comment: What I meant is to use it without metadata and Task Library (ImageSegmenter) with plain Interpeter, Support Library and postprocessing steps. Can you also provide a notebook with preprocessing(Normalization etc) and postprocessing steps?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new in this model conversion and tflite thing, so I don't have any idea how can I use a plain interpreter, that's why I was using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/android) opensource ImageSegmenter of tflite in which they provide deeplab v3 model by default, So I changed it with my tflite converted model of u2net, and was expecting results. Can you describe me that plain interpreter working in detail, I'm sure that will help me alot ..

Comment: Where is the original repo of this u2net to take a look?

Comment: here it is ..  https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net

Comment: I basically want a model to accurately remove the backgrounds from the images in android .. other than deeplab, because it does not do a better job in this case ..

Comment: Ok, I will get into this and keep you informed.

Comment: It seems that the preprocess steps are a little bit confusing https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/blob/f2b8e4ac1c4fbe90daba8707bca051a0ec830bf6/data_loader.py#L137 I will try to reproduce firstly in colab with Python code and then get into android

Comment: sure @Farmaker , and thanks for the time and efforts you are doing ..

Comment: I have made great progress and I see a grayscale bitmap on screen of device. Consider it done. I will paste the code later and I will upload a sample app on my github.

Comment: sure, thanks, I'll be waiting ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write a long answer here. Getting in touch with the github repo of U2Net it leaves you with the effort to examine the pre and post-processing steps so you can aply the same inside the android project.

First of all preprocessing:
In the `u2net_test.py` file you can see at [this line](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/blob/master/u2net_test.py#L73) that all the images are preprocessed with function `ToTensorLab(flag=0)`. Navigating to this you see that with flag=0 the preprocessing is this:

```
else: # with rgb color (flag = 0)
            tmpImg = np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1],3))
            image = image/np.max(image)
            if image.shape[2]==1:
                tmpImg[:,:,0] = (image[:,:,0]-0.485)/0.229
                tmpImg[:,:,1] = (image[:,:,0]-0.485)/0.229
                tmpImg[:,:,2] = (image[:,:,0]-0.485)/0.229
            else:
                tmpImg[:,:,0] = (image[:,:,0]-0.485)/0.229
                tmpImg[:,:,1] = (image[:,:,1]-0.456)/0.224
                tmpImg[:,:,2] = (image[:,:,2]-0.406)/0.225
```

Pay attention to 2 steps.

First every color pixel value is divided by the maximum value of all color pixel values:

```
image = image/np.max(image)
```

and

Second at every color pixel value is applied mean and std:

```
tmpImg[:,:,0] = (image[:,:,0]-0.485)/0.229
tmpImg[:,:,1] = (image[:,:,1]-0.456)/0.224
tmpImg[:,:,2] = (image[:,:,2]-0.406)/0.225
```

So basically in Kotlin if you have a bitmap you have to do something like:

```
fun bitmapToFloatArray(bitmap: Bitmap):
                Array<Array<Array<FloatArray>>> {
            
            val width: Int = bitmap.width
            val height: Int = bitmap.height
            val intValues = IntArray(width * height)
            bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)

            // Create aa array to find the maximum value
            val fourDimensionalArray = Array(1) {
                Array(320) {
                    Array(320) {
                        FloatArray(3)
                    }
                }
            }
            // https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/blob/f2b8e4ac1c4fbe90daba8707bca051a0ec830bf6/data_loader.py#L204
            for (i in 0 until width - 1) {
                for (j in 0 until height - 1) {
                    val pixelValue: Int = intValues[i * width + j]
                    fourDimensionalArray[0][i][j][0] =
                        Color.red(pixelValue)
                            .toFloat()
                    fourDimensionalArray[0][i][j][1] =
                        Color.green(pixelValue)
                            .toFloat()
                    fourDimensionalArray[0][i][j][2] =
                        Color.blue(pixelValue).toFloat()
                }

            }
            // Convert multidimensional array to 1D
            val oneDFloatArray = ArrayList<Float>()

            for (m in fourDimensionalArray[0].indices) {
                for (x in fourDimensionalArray[0][0].indices) {
                    for (y in fourDimensionalArray[0][0][0].indices) {
                        oneDFloatArray.add(fourDimensionalArray[0][m][x][y])
                    }
                }
            }

            val maxValue: Float = oneDFloatArray.maxOrNull() ?: 0f
            //val minValue: Float = oneDFloatArray.minOrNull() ?: 0f

            // Final array that is going to be used with interpreter
            val finalFourDimensionalArray = Array(1) {
                Array(320) {
                    Array(320) {
                        FloatArray(3)
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i in 0 until width - 1) {
                for (j in 0 until height - 1) {
                    val pixelValue: Int = intValues[i * width + j]
                    finalFourDimensionalArray[0][i][j][0] =
                        ((Color.red(pixelValue).toFloat() / maxValue) - 0.485f) / 0.229f
                    finalFourDimensionalArray[0][i][j][1] =
                        ((Color.green(pixelValue).toFloat() / maxValue) - 0.456f) / 0.224f
                    finalFourDimensionalArray[0][i][j][2] =
                        ((Color.blue(pixelValue).toFloat() / maxValue) - 0.406f) / 0.225f
                }

            }

            return finalFourDimensionalArray
        }
```

Then this array is fed inside the interpreter and as your model has multiple outputs we are using `runForMultipleInputsOutputs`:

```
// Convert Bitmap to Float array
             val inputStyle = ImageUtils.bitmapToFloatArray(loadedBitmap)

            // Create arrays with size 1,320,320,1
            val output1 =  Array(1) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { FloatArray(1)}}}
            val output2 =  Array(1) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { FloatArray(1)}}}
            val output3 =  Array(1) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { FloatArray(1)}}}
            val output4 =  Array(1) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { FloatArray(1)}}}
            val output5 =  Array(1) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { FloatArray(1)}}}
            val output6 =  Array(1) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { Array(CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE) { FloatArray(1)}}}

            val outputs: MutableMap<Int,
                    Any> = HashMap()
            outputs[0] = output1
            outputs[1] = output2
            outputs[2] = output3
            outputs[3] = output4
            outputs[4] = output5
            outputs[5] = output6
          
            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            val array = arrayOf(inputStyle)
            interpreterDepth.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(array, outputs)
```

Then we use the first output of the interpreter as [you can see at](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/blob/master/u2net_test.py#L111) `u2net_test.py` file. (I have also printed results of [line 112](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/blob/master/u2net_test.py#L112) but it seems that it has no effect. You are free to try that with min and max value of the color pixel values).
So we have the post proseccing like you can see at the [save_output function](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/blob/f2b8e4ac1c4fbe90daba8707bca051a0ec830bf6/u2net_test.py#L39):

```
// Convert output array to Bitmap
val (finalBitmapGrey, finalBitmapBlack) = ImageUtils.convertArrayToBitmapTensorFlow(
                output1, CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE,
                CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE
            )
```

where the above function will be like:

```
fun convertArrayToBitmapTensorFlow(
            imageArray: Array<Array<Array<FloatArray>>>,
            imageWidth: Int,
            imageHeight: Int
        ): Bitmap {
            val conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // see other conf types
            val grayToneImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, conf)

            for (x in imageArray[0].indices) {
                for (y in imageArray[0][0].indices) {
                    val color = Color.rgb(
                        //
                        (((imageArray[0][x][y][0]) * 255f).toInt()),
                        (((imageArray[0][x][y][0]) * 255f).toInt()),
                        (((imageArray[0][x][y][0]) * 255f).toInt())
                    )

                    // this y, x is in the correct order!!!
                    grayToneImage.setPixel(y, x, color)
                }
            }
            return grayToneImage
        }
```

then this grayscale image you can use it as you want.

Due to multiple steps of the preprocessing I used directly interpreter with no additional libraries. I will try later in the week if you can insert metadata with all the steps but I doubt that.

If you need some clarifications please do not hesitate to ask me.

Colab notebook [link](https://github.com/farmaker47/Portrait_creator/blob/master/U2Net_to_TFLite.ipynb)

Happy coding

Comment: Hey , the model runs very slow on android . Is there any way to make the application more smooth which uses image segmentation model .

Comment: I have used numThreads = 8 and the total processing time is about 10 seconds. Try to use also GPU delegate which I think it can handle this model as it works with floats.

Comment: Hey , the current version of code at their github which is tensorflow examples runs smooth . They have optimised i guess . Just that accuracy is bit on the lower side . But in coming time it might improve . Thanks for reverting .

Comment: Also , can you  suggest me some good tutorials for image segmentation implementation on android using tflite . That would be really helpful

Comment: I do not know any tutorials, but I basically rely on the original android segmentation example here 
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/android and also at my github where I have refactored the code to use CameraX https://github.com/farmaker47/Update_image_segmentation
If you need something more ping me

Comment: thanks @Farmaker, that works and shows a greyscale image in the output, however, I'm a little curious about one thing that how can I get the real background removed image in the output other than this grey masked image ..?

Comment: Instead of creating a black/white image at the end ...create a black/transparent one. Then use porterduf mode like https://github.com/farmaker47/Segmentation_and_Style_Transfer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soloupis/sample/ocr_keras/fragments/segmentation/OcrViewModel.kt#L139 ...you can get more info here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode so basically you will have a backgroung image and the black/transparent one

Comment: I'm having issues in this line:
val (finalBitmapGrey, finalBitmapBlack) = ImageUtils.convertArrayToBitmapTensorFlow(
                output1, CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE,
                CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE
  )
it throws an error:
Destructuring declaration initializer of type Bitmap must have a 'component1()' function.
Destructuring declaration initializer of type Bitmap must have a 'component2()' function.

I think it is not assigning values to both of them  ..
for more clarification, can you share the source code of the test app in which you tested this model with interpreter directly?

Comment: Yes you are right. Make it like val finalBitmapGrey = ImageUtils.convertArrayToBitmapTensorFlow( output1, CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE, CONTENT_IMAGE_SIZE ) . I haven't uploaded the project somewhere.

Comment: Yes i did the same and i've got the grey scaled image by using your code but when i'm using porterduf code for getting cropped image instead of masking as you mentioned above in the comment. That function is getting null as i passed both scaledImage and finalBitmapGrey in it.

Comment: I think this is a different problem. You can start a new question at SO and tag me.

Comment: I have opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903988/get-cropped-image-bitmap-using-u2net-model-in-android. Please have a look on it. Thanks.

Comment: @Farmaker can you please populate your github with you google colab file / jupyter notebook . In need of it for proper understanding of the process . Great work man.

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I have populated the repo. https://github.com/farmaker47/Portrait_creator

Comment: Thank-you very much . Really appreciate .

Comment: @Farmaker can you please help with this 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153893/deeplab-image-segmenter-tflite-model-gives-non-masked-bitmap-and-white-bitmap-as